# Using Flow.js with React compound components

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to figure out how to use Flow.js types with [compound React components.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEGg-3pIHlE&t=1501s)

For example, let's say I have component `A` like so:

```
type Props = {title: string};
const A = ({title}: Props) => <span>{title}</span>;
```

And `TitleProvider` like so:

```
const TitleProvider = () => {
  return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
    title: 'Foo',
  });
};
```

Then I am using these two components as compound components like so:

```
<TitleProvider>
  <A />
</TitleProvider>
```

This will fail because the initial call to React.createElement will create the `A` component without the required `title` prop.

I want to keep using compound components (I don't want to pass down component class or use render props). I also want the title prop of `A` to stay as required (I don't want to have the type like `{title?: string}`).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but you could provide default props. `A.defaultProps = {title: ''}` Flow is clever enough to handle default props. Image the following component `const B = ({title}: Props) => <i>{title.length ? title: 'empty'}</i>` not only flow would complain but you'd also get TypeError.

Comment: IMHO, it's kinda violation of the very idea of components, since we want to reason about `A` component and its props without any knowledge of how it's going to be "monkey patched" by anyone out there. So, your intention to not ease prop types of `A` is good, but `TitleProvider` logic is not OK (maybe then it's fine to have some redundant props defined out there?).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use React Hooks and Context api-s.

Create context provider:

```
// @flow
import * as React from "react";

export const TitleContext: React.Context<{
    title: string
}> = React.createContext({
    title: string
});

const TitleProvider = (props: {children: React.Node}) => {
  return <TitleContext.Provider value={{title: "Foo"}}>
      {props.children}
  <TitleContext.Provider>
};
```

Next, create A, that used TitleProvider:

```
// @flow
import * as React from "react";
import {TitleContext} from "...";

const A = () => {
    const {title} = useContext(TitleContext); // flow infer type 'string' for title
    return <span>{title}</span>
};
```

Finally, compound TitleProvider and A:

```
<TitleProvider>
  <A />
</TitleProvider>
```

Comment: The idea behind the question was more about making flow.js work together with `cloneElement`, but thanks for the answer regardless!